# Django Rest Framework not saving all foreign key objects

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am going to create a conference and select multiple departments, it is working when I send post request but in GET resquest not getting objects.

```
class DepartmentModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    conference = models.ForeignKey('ConferenceModel', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True,
                                   related_name='conference_departments')

class ConferenceModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class DepartmentField(serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        pk = super(DepartmentField, self).to_representation(value)
        try:
            item = DepartmentModel.objects.get(pk=pk)
            serializer = DepartmentSerializer(item)
            return serializer.data
        except DepartmentModel.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def get_choices(self, cutoff=None):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        if queryset is None:
            return {}

        return OrderedDict([(item.id, str(item)) for item in queryset])

class ConferenceModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    conference_departments = DepartmentField(queryset=DepartmentModel.objects.all(), many=True)
    meeting_participants = SelectItemField(model='account.User', extra_field=['first_name', 'last_name'], many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ConferenceModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

**request**

```
{
    "conference_departments": [
        3, 4, 5, 7, 8
    ],
    "meeting_participants": [
        10, 12, 15
    ],
    "description": "Bla bla bla"
}
```

it returns the expected result but If I want to save another object and get all objects it does not return objects but the latest one does.

here you can see from the image below

[image]

id: 19 is the latest saved object it returns department objects but id: 18 does not!

can anybody help me please? any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```py
class DepartmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    ...

    class Meta:
        model = DepartmentModel
        fields = '__all__'

class ConferenceModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    conference_departments = DepartmentSerializer(required=False, many=True)
    meeting_participants = SelectItemField(model='account.User', extra_field=['first_name', 'last_name'], many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ConferenceModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

[Nested relationships](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships)

[Writable nested serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers)